# Dapper parameters not being replaced

Tags: c#, sql, dapper, roles

I've been using Dapper on this project for months and there has been no issues. But now I have to use raw SQL instead of stored procedures with dapper to create and alter *Users* and *Roles* in the database since `sp_addrolemember` is deprecated now.

I'm using this as my dapper code

```
conn.Open();
var p = new DynamicParameters();
p.Add("@UserLogin", user);
p.Add("@UserRole", role);
conn.Execute("Create User @UserLogin", p);
conn.Execute("ALTER ROLE @UserRole ADD MEMBER @UserLogin", p);
```

I keep getting the same error:

> Invalid syntax at @UserLogin

I'm passing my `domain\username` as the login and I've tried it without `domain\`, too. Same thing. Can someone shed some light on this?

Comment: Have you tried to use a regular class instead of the DynamicParameters class?

Comment: You can't use parameters to represent system names like table, columns or even users or roles. It is not a Dapper problem

Comment: That's kind of what I was thinking. Could you provide a link to documentation for this? I tried looking for that type of information myself in case that was the reason.

Comment: role parametric is string?

Answer (score -2):

I'm not familiar with Dapper, but you could try embedding the parameter values into the SQL strings you are sending for execution:

```
conn.Open();
conn.Execute("Create User " + user);
conn.Execute("ALTER ROLE " + role + " ADD MEMBER " + user);
```

Note that this comes with security risks and may cause other problems!

Comment: `Note that this comes with security risks and may cause other problems!` Then you probably shouldn't recommend doing so..